# App crashing since adding a retrieve function from my Firebase database

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android development and I am trying to make a simple app with a navigation drawer, in which when the fragment named as `Main()` is opened by the user it will display the name I have added in my Firebase database.

But since I added the code to retrieve the data from the cloud, the app is crashing. Please help!

Below is my Main Activity in which I set the default view to Fragment `Main` (Which by the way was working before trying to retrieve the data).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Main fragment = new Main();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Below is the code in my 'Main' fragment to retrieve the data.

```
public class Main extends Fragment {

private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
TextView show;


public Main() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    //show = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.show);


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    show = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.show);
    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Name");
    mdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String ret = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            show.setText("Name: " + ret);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            show.setText("Name:");
        }
    });


    return v;
}

}
```

And below the .xml of the fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.technobotik.www.learnac.Main">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<TextView
    android:text="Name:"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/show"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>
```

Please Help!
Thank You!

Comment: can you post your error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If database location `Name` contains no value, the `DataSnapshot` returned by the listener returns null for `getValue()`.  You need to check that a value exists before applying `toString()` to the result:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        String ret = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        show.setText("Name: " + ret);
    } else {
        show.setText("Name: NULL");
    }

}
```